# Dynamically close dialog

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

In my jQM - Backbone app I add a dialog programmatically if a certain condition is true, like this

```
$('body').append('<div data-role="dialog" id="interlink" data-theme="b" data-close-btn="none" data-url="insignificant"></div> ');
// remove dialog from DOM on pagehide
$("#interlink").on('pagehide', function () {
    $(this).remove();
    // remove this views popup-containers 
    $('#interlink-video-popup-popup').remove();
});
```

Beside other content in the dialog there is a button to open a popup widget to play a video clip and a close button to close the dialog. The code for closing the dialog looks like this:

```
backBtnHandler: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#interlink').dialog('close');
    $(this).remove(); // all DOM listeners get removed as well by jQuery
}
```

This works all well if the video clip is watched in full length, the popup widget closes on ended and the user clicks the dialog close button to close it.
A requirement is when the video clip is playing and the user scans another NFC tag the video should stop, trigger an ended event and close the popup. This is also working, however the dialog should also close. Here is a simplified code snippet with a timeout to simulate a NFC scan:

```
INTERPRETOUR.interlinkVideoPlayer = $('#interlink-video-player')[0];
// bind onended event to close the popup   
$(INTERPRETOUR.interlinkVideoPlayer).on('ended', function() {
    $('#interlink-video-popup').popup('close');
    INTERPRETOUR.interlinkVideoPlayer = 'undefined';
    $('#interlink-back-btn').trigger('click');
});
// play video
INTERPRETOUR.interlinkVideoPlayer.src = 'http://mydomain.ca' + this.model.get('video')[0].url; 
INTERPRETOUR.interlinkVideoPlayer.play();
setTimeout(function() {
    $.publish('item', '2479');
}, 5000);
```

The issue is that `$('#interlink-back-btn').trigger('click');` invokes the `backBtnHandler` but `pagehid`e is never triggered and so the dialog doesn't close.

Any help to resolve this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Omar: to be more precisely #interlink is a Backbone view and utilizes Underscore template engine to populate the data.

Comment: For `pagehide` try this `$(document).on('pagehide', '#interlink', function`

Comment: @Omar: thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately, didn't make any difference.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Where is `interlink-back-btn` located exactly? Popup or dialog?

Comment: Ok I got an idea. Instead of invoking back-btn, close dialog upon closing the popup `popupafterclose` as in this example. http://fiddle.jshell.net/xMu8K/3/

Comment: Here another method http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/ZXq74/

Comment: @Omar: thanks, closing the dialog on popupafterclose is working!

Comment: Shall I add an answer?

Comment: Which fix you liked most?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of invoking a button using `.trigger('click')`, bind closing when `popupafterclose` event triggers.

> **[Demo 1](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mVU5h/)** / **[Demo 2](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/ZXq74/)**

**Static Popup**

```
$('#popupID').on('popupafterclose', function () {
  $('#dialogID').dialog('close');
});
```

**Dynamically generated Popup**

```
$(document).on('popupafterclose', '#popupID', function () {
  $('#dialogID').dialog('close');
});
```